# setting up permissions by "Client Status" field on Client entity

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

We have a few "Clients" marked as "Employee" in our CRM 2011 system.

How would we create a security role to only allow certain users to access client records that have the above criteria?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the built-in security system. The security roles grant access based on record level, not on value level.

It should be possible to create a plugin, which handles the PreRetrieve message for this entity. This plugin could check your custom criteria and if the user is not allowed to open the record, you could throw an exception to cancel the operation.

Keep in mind that, for a 100% solution, you would also have to handle RetrieveMultiple, Execute, ...

Comment: Thanks for verifying that and suggesting a practical alternative and happy holidays!